# Fragment layout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Fragment layout in my app. but I want to use The code that I written in Oncreate Bundle, so how I can write my code in OncreateView. 
here is the code of fragment layout.

```
    public class Text extends Fragment { 
    public Text(){} 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_to_speech, container,  false);     
    return rootView;
   }
```

so where I have to use oncreate bundle, or can I write same code in OncreateView.

help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little more? Are you talking about getting the bundle from onCreate inside the activity, into the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can get bundle like below if you passed some data by bundle.

Bundle bundle = getArguments();

Answer (score 0):

We use this method for it.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
}
```

Comment: but where to use above code, that you given.like inside the OncreateView or outside .

Comment: inside the fragment like you're using `onCreateView`

Comment: outside of `onCreateView`

Comment: I wrote My Code in the onActivityCreated , outside the onCreateView            but I am getting "app stopped working"

Comment: Before to write code run your project and check error. I don't think so this method can create problem to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

[Here the full description about Fragment lifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Meanwhile, onCreateView must get the view from the Activity.  [here some usefull tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

wish that was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Fragment class doesn't have oncreate() method.You can write code in oncreateView().Check the Fragment lifecycle. Follow the link below

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html